# Mongo db custom search on text

Tags: mongodb

```
{
name:"zpp test"
}
{
name:"test"
}
{
name:"test111"
}
{
name:"test surya"
}
```

Now i need to search with `test` keyword

I want to fectch records like

Exact match first

```
{
name:"test"
}
{
name:'test111'
}

{
name:"test surya"
}
{
name:"zpp test", 
}
```

Priority:

```
Exact match first

Next starts with

Next contains
```

I need to search on multiple fileds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for this kind of search.

Here is the example of search on username and name.

```
Users.find({ $or: [{ username: { $regex: new RegExp(query, 'ig') } }, { name: { $regex: new RegExp(query, 'ig') } }] }).exec((err, result) => {
//do something 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with this aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $addFields: {
        "priority": { // add new field called priority
            $switch: {
                "branches": [
                    { case: { $eq: [ "$name", "test" ] }, then: 1 }, // set priority to one for an exact match
                    { case: { $eq: [ { $substr: [ "$name", 0, 4 ] }, "test" ] }, then: 2 }, // set priority to 2 for a "starts with" match
                    { case: { $ne: [ { $indexOfBytes: [ "$name", "test" ] }, -1 ] }, then: 3 }, // set priority to 3 for a "contains" match
                ],
                default: null // set priority to null if no match
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $match: { "priority": { $ne: null } } // filter out non-matching documents
}, {
    $sort: { "priority": 1 } // sort by priority
})
```

An alternative which may be appealing depending on your data volumes and the complexity of your final query might be this. Please note, however, that this will most likely come with a performance penalty because we're evaluating all documents effectively three times:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $facet: { // create three separate aggregation pipelines
        "exact": [{ // one holding all documents...
            $match: { "name": "test" } // ...that are exactly matched
        }, {
            $addFields: { "priority": 1 } // ...and an additional field "priority": 1
        }],
        "startsWith": [{ // a 2nd one holding all documents...
            $match: { "name": /^test/ } // ...that match the "starts with" filter
        }, {
            $addFields: { "priority": 2 } // ...and an additional field "priority": 2
        }],
        "contains": [{ // a 3rd one holding all documents...
            $match: { "name": /test/ } // ...that match the "contains" filter
        }, {
            $addFields: { "priority": 3 } // ...and an additional field "priority": 3
        }]
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "allResults": { // merge the results of the three pipelines
            $concatArrays: [ "$exact", "$startsWith", "$contains" ]
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$allResults" // and flatten the resulting array into individual documents
}, {
    $sort: { "allResults.priority": 1 } // sort all documents by priority
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$allResults._id", // group by document id
        "result": { $first: "$$ROOT" } // and keep only the one with the highest priority
    }
}, {
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: "$result.allResults" // restore the original document structure
    }
}, {
    $sort: { "priority": 1 } // and sort the results by "priority" again
})
```